# Purchase Requisition for asset services

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I have a task to modify a purchase requisition `(tcode:me51n)` with item category `(service)` and account assignment `(asset services)` for filling automatically the asset field `(ESKN-ANLN1)` based on specific service-activity number `(ESLL-SRVPOS)`. These fields are at items details screen and asset number at account assignment tab.

Until now I have achieved to link an asset with specific service in service master through classification. This information is stored at AUSP. Also, I am taking the activity number using a field symbol and asset number with select from AUSP. The problem is that the asset value doesn’t have an export at screen. I have tried `user exits EXIT_SAPLMLSK_001 from enhancement SRVESLL, exits from enhancement mereq001 and the exit EXIT_SAPLKACB_002 from ACCOBL01` and also the `badi ME_PROCESS_REQ_CUST`, but I couldn’t achieve to pass the asset number as export to screen.

Could any expert help me?

Thanks